# Disable Telerik's function in DotNetNuke

Tags: css, telerik, dotnetnuke

I have installed DNN module on remote machine, but it have destroyed css styling, so I checked it via firebug and all styles that destroy my module are in telerik.web.ui.webresource.axd, so I cannot overwrite them easily. I can't also find them in easy way via total commander. Is there any safe way to disable teleriks caching functions?

(I disabled teleriks module but it totally crashed site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS management in DNN is a mess; since the css are usually set up in the skin I would recommend either **not using the default skin** for your site front-facing portion (keep it at least for admin though, since most telerik controls live there) or to **define your css much more agressively** by being very specific.

[Specificity and precedence](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/precedence.html)  tweaking in DNN is always a good idea, since you may find yourself surrounded by third-party content that doesn't play nice (or is definitely rude by overusing the !important css styling). Specify everything about your styles/modules in order to be sure that your style is applied to your content.